# How to compile Kodi on Mac for IMX6

Tags: xcode, macos, kodi

I have the Kodi source code from github.com and I want to compile the source for an external media player.

I am able to compile the source to run on the Mac (El Capitan) using xcode.

Can I compile the source into an img (or file I can convert to an img) from which I can then create an SD card for an IMX6 Freescale device?  I don't know Xcode very well and can't see how I would add a new target (if that is it) or if I need additional libraries or source to compile something for a linux platform.

I basically have a CuboxTV but I want to use Kodi v17 (krypton) so want to see if I am able to have that running on my CuboxTV (with v17).

Kodi v17 compiles and runs on the Mac - I just need to find out how I can compile it to run on a linux platform using an IMX6.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

CuboxTV comes preloaded with OpenELEC, which is a Linux distribution specifically designed for Kodi. 
If you want to compile the source code of KODI from github for the i.MX6 platform and write it to an SD card, you will need to take a distribution from the Cubox Download page (Debian, Archlinux, etc) to install Kodi on top of it.

You can take a look at the kodi-imx PKGBUILD for Archlinux in order to check the compiling instructions and dependencies.

https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/blob/master/alarm/kodi-imx/PKGBUILD